# Best way to store a list of points

Tags: .net

I want to store (mass storage) a list of points; to be more precise it is a list that contains  a number not defined (but not exceeding 200) of groups of coordinates, where each group represents an *area* (a rectangle). This *area* could be for example a [`Rect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.aspx) structure.

**What is the best way for me:**
In order of importance:

1. Occupied space in storage memory (obviously less is better).
2. Ease with which the file is modified (would be better to be able to identify and change the single coordinate, instead of rewrite the entire file due to a change).
3. Speed ​​reading.
4. Speed writing.

I already had some ideas on how to set up the work (for example simple text format managed by a custom class, serialization, access database (I can only use an access database), ...), but what is the best solution?

Comment: This is an extremely subjective question. "Best" is going to depend on your personal preference. A simple binary solution would be the most memory effecient, but it's also one of the more difficult options to code and debug. Text takes up more memory, but is a bit easier to read. XML is one of the easier solutions to program, but it is much less memory effecient.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 It's a subjective questione because it's a subjective work. Anyway i wrote what i mean with _best_.

Comment: Do you want this as a local file storage, or is a data base alright?

Comment: @ReedCopsey If a database is closest to my requests i would prefer a database (but i can only use a access database), otherwise i I would prefer a local file.

Comment: @gliderkite You can only use an access database?

Comment: @ReedCopsey yes, only an access database.

Comment: @gliderkite Well, Access doesn't (natively) support any form of spatial data, so you're probably better off using a separate local file type, then - my answer should be relevant in that case.

Comment: Is one group of coordinates limited to rectangle or do you mean any closed pologon?  Or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the problem set addressed by most GIS storage formats.  There are many different formats available, all with various advantages and disadvantages.

The OGR project supports [many formats](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) for GIS style vector data, nearly all of which support storage of area features with most of the characteristics you're after.  One of the "newer" ones here would be [ESRI's File Geodatabase](https://web.archive.org/web/20130704110629/http://resources.arcgis.com:80/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api) format, which is supported in .NET via OGR's C# wrappers.

Alternatively, many database systems, such as SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and others support storing spatial data directly in the database.  This may be a bit "heavyweight" depending on your needs, but will support very high performance and scalability.

Comment: GIS stands for what? Have you any references to OGR's C# wrappers?

Comment: @gliderkite GIS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system  OGR's C# wrappers are auto-generated, and part of the OGR project.  They're included in the binaries here (http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/)  The "docs" are basically just the C++ docs, though.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a native spatial type formats which can be used to store polygons

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895267.aspx

For manipulation, you can load the data into an object to read/modify/validate new points in each polygon.

**EDIT:** Jason Follas has a good exploration of spatial types here:
http://jasonfollas.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/sql-server-2008-spatial-data-part-1.aspx

**EDIT:** I see the OP edited in that he can only use an access database, so my answer no longer applies... but I will leave it as-is in case somebody else finds this question *without* such a DB limitation.

As for the OP, using only an access database limits your abilities quite a bit. 
I would consider two tables: **Area** and **Points** with a simple one-to-many relationship.